# Gnuplot axes x and y

Tags: gnuplot

I have trouble with gnuplot graph. Axis x and y are bad writing.
Script in bash is here.

```
echo "set terminal png 8;
set output name.png
set multiplot
set timefmt '%s';
set title \"$LEGEND\";
set xdata time;
set format x$CASOVY_FORMAT;
set xrange [:]
set yrange [:]
unset colorbox
plot '$docasnyadr/data_timestamp_1' u 1:2 t '' w lines lw 1 lc 1
plot '$docasnyadr/data_timestamp_2' u 1:2 t '' w lines lw 1 lc 2
plot '$docasnyadr/data_timestamp_3' u 1:2 t '' w lines lw 1 lc 3" | gnuplot
```

Data's files have format `timestamp any_number`. Here is a picture:
[image]

I need auto xrange and auto yrange. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of notes:

It looks like you want to plot three sets of data on the same plot with different colors.  In that case you don't necessarily need multiplot (which is meant to make completely separate plots in separate plot areas), so you could use the command

```
plot '$docasnyadr/data_timestamp_1' u 1:2 t '' w lines lw 1, \
'$docasnyadr/data_timestamp_2' u 1:2 t '' w lines lw 1, \
'$docasnyadr/data_timestamp_3' u 1:2 t '' w lines lw 1
```

instead of the three plot commands.  This way the line color automatically increments also.

The x axes on your plot look strange not because of an autorange issue, but because the y tic marks have two digits for some of the plots (e.g. '98') and three digits (e.g. '103') for others.

If you want the three data sets to be next to each other, you will probably have to offset them manually:

```
plot '$docasnyadr/data_timestamp_1' u 1:2 t '' w lines lw 1, \
'$docasnyadr/data_timestamp_2' u 1:($2+offset1) t '' w lines lw 1, \
'$docasnyadr/data_timestamp_3' u 1:($2+offset2) t '' w lines lw 1
```

Otherwise you could experiment with multiple y axes.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the lines

```
set xrange [:]
set yrange [:]
```

with

```
set autoscale xy
```

-- http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node157.html